# Refactor SQL for speed: use CASE instead UNION ALL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Table T(user_id, bucket,  profile, money, model, type).

All columns: "bucket", "model" and "type" are having low cardinality (<5)

I need to calculate several aggregates: count(distinct user_id), sum(money)
grouped by following criteria:

```
1) group by bucket, model
2) group by bucket, model, type
3) group by bucket where type='A'
4) group by bucket where profile='adult'
```

and return it as a single result.

My current approach is:

```
select bucket, model, NULL as type, count(distinct user_id), sum(money), 'model' as helper from T 
group by bucket, model
UNION ALL
select bucket, model, type, count(distinct user_id), sum(money), 'model_type' as helper from T 
group by bucket, model, type
UNION ALL
select bucket, NULL as model, 'A' as type, count(distinct user_id), sum(money), 'type_A' as helper from T  
where type='A' group by bucket 
UNION ALL
select bucket, NULL as model, NULL as type, count(distinct user_id), sum(money), 'profile_adult' as helper 
from T  where profile='adult' group by bucket
```

The source table is big (millions of rows, Redshift) and the query is slow.

Every subquery above returns less than 10 rows.

I think it is slow because it is scanned 4 times ( 4 unions in SQL).

Is it possible to achieve it in single table scan?
Since it Redshift, adding indexes is not a solution.

I was thinking about using CASE operator, but cannot figure how to make it work here.

Comment: You didn't show the distribution definition of the table. This is a fundamental design and performance factor. If you distribute on _bucket_, then this query can probably done in parallel (not sure about the UNION ALL parts thought). Any performance question should also include some kind of analysis of the query plan.

Comment: How many rows are does each subquery produce?  There might be other ways to arrive at the same answer.

Comment: Table is not distributed on bucket. 
All  columns: "bucket", "model" and "type" are having low cardinality.
Every subquery returns  less than 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than querying the table four times to perform similar aggregations on different populations, what if you pre-aggregated the data to a higher level, then performed your four major aggregations on that data set?

In that scenario, you could store the output of the following query in a table:

```
SELECT
    bucket
   ,model
   ,Type -- you could replace with a CASE expression that returns 'A' or NULL
   ,profile -- you could replace with a CASE expressions that returns 'Adult' or NULL
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
   ,SUM(money)
FROM t
GROUP BY
    bucket
   ,model
   ,Type -- you could replace with a CASE expression that returns 'A' or NULL
   ,profile -- you could replace with a CASE expressions that returns 'Adult' or NULL
```

Once that's done, you could then use the same aggregation logic as your original post against this smaller data set to produce your final results.